# Prevent customers from adding products from a certain category and show notice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I tried to find a code to prevent customers from adding products that are in a specific category to the cart and showing a notice "Sorry, you can not buy this product at this time; please try later"

I found a code below, but it completely hides add to cart button, and I don't want it to happen. It should show add to cart button but does not allow items to be added to the cart.

```
// Custom conditional function that check for specific product categories
function check_for_defined_product_categories( $product_id ) {
    $targeted_terms = array( 't-shirts' ); 
    return has_term( $targeted_terms, 'product_cat', $product_id );
}
// Disable add to cart button (conditionally)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $product_id = $product->get_parent_id() > 0 ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if( check_for_defined_product_categories( $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Hope you can help me with this issue. Thank you so much!

- Prevent products (belong to a specific category) to be added to cart
- Show notice: "Sorry, you can not buy this product at this time; please try later"
- Do not hide add to cart button

Comment: Fist you need to use proper hook which in your case will be woocommerce_add_to_cart from there you can loop what is in the cart and based on the items in cart to remove or allow product to be added. then you call wc_add_notice()

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet in your functions.php

```
function exclude_products_from_cart($cart_item_key, $product_id) {
    //Add one or many categories you want to compare
    if( has_term( array( 'accessories'), 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
        wc_add_notice(__('Sorry, you can not buy this product at this time; please try later','woocommerce'),'notice'); // The name of the notice type - either error, success or notice
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart','exclude_products_from_cart',10,2);
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you so much for your response. The code has prevented customers from adding products to the cart and showed notice, but it still shows "..... has been added to your cart." above the custom notice, "Sorry, you can not buy this product at this time....".
https://imgur.com/l4TtKyW
Please find the attached image. 
Can you help to hide "..... has been added to your cart."? I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: I added a short code to your current code, and it works perfectly as I expected. Thank you, Martin, for your help in resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function exclude_products_from_cart($cart_item_key, $product_id) {
if( has_term( array( 'accessories'), 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
    WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
    wc_add_notice(__('Sorry, this product is not available now; please try tommorrow','woocommerce'),'error');
    add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart','exclude_products_from_cart',10,2);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).